# rapidxml unexpected type alloc_func

Tags: c++, rapidxml

I am using rapidxml to parse and create xml-files in my projects.
Problem is that in one project it worked fine, and in another I got

```
rapidxml.hpp(385): error C2226: syntax error : unexpected type 'alloc_func'
```

Error.

is there any quick fix for this problem ? And why is it happening in the first place ?

Answer (score 1):

Known problem - the description (and fix) can be found in this boost ticket:

- https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5281

Comment: yes, thanks, I already saw that page, but I thought maybe someone has a solution without adding extra modules from boost ?

Comment: If you can find another way to avoid the ``alloc_func`` name collision, you don't need any extra modules.

Comment: Well, after renaming this function it did compile, but I'am not sure if it is acceptable to change source code of extra modules, nevertheless for now it looks like the only reasonable solution